# How to call addEventListener to ScrollView in cocos2d-x 3.6?

Tags: c++, scrollview, cocos2d-x

Could anyone give an example?
I try the following code, it always shows up error "No viable conversion from xxxxx" on the line of addEventListener while compiling.

```
// create a scrollview and add event listener
auto scrollView = cocos2d::ui::ScrollView::create();
scrollView->addEventListener(CC_CALLBACK_2(GameMenuLayer::didScrollItemInfoPanel, this));

...

// the callback function
void GameMenuLayer::didScrollItemInfoPanel(Ref* ref, cocos2d::ui::ScrollviewEventType eventType) {
    cclog("did scroll...");
}
```

I see the callback function definition is as the following, so how should I modify my code?

```
typedef std::function<void(Ref*, EventType)> ccScrollViewCallback;
```

I have tried the old method and it works fine, but it shows a warning message that old method is deprecated.

```
scrollView->addEventListenerScrollView(this, SEL_ScrollViewEvent(&GameMenuLayer::didScrollItemInfoPanel));
```

Answer (score 1):

6, 3.7 I use the following without deprecated warnings. You are very close, here is the example. One cast and all will work.

Add event in YOUR_CLASS.cpp:

```
 scrollView->addEventListener((ui::ScrollView::ccScrollViewCallback)CC_CALLBACK_2(YOUR_CLASS::scrollEvent,this));
```

add event method declaration in YOUR_CLASS.h:

```
void scrollEvent(Ref* ref, ui::ScrollView::EventType EventType);
```

And implement the event method.